# React hooks, setting state on select

Tags: reactjs, select, react-hooks

I'm trying to add sorting feature to my data but I have some issues, I decided to try to play with React hooks a bit and not sure if I do something wrong, the problem is that when I select some value by Select, then eventho state has been changed, there is no differences on the page, after I click second time in another value (if I click same element then nothing changes) then everything starts to work normally and each time I click some value, the different way of sorting is applied. Why it doesn't want to work properly since the very beginning?

EDIT:
First in Parent component I fetch data which then I pass through the props:

Parent:

```
  const [data, setData] = useState("")

useEffect(() => getDeviceDataTotal(), [])

  const getDeviceDataTotal = () => {
    console.log('refresh clicked')
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/device")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((res) => setData(res))
      .catch(err => {
        throw err;
      });
  };




<Route
    exact
    path="/"
    render={() => <Dashboard classes={classes} data={data} refresh={getDeviceDataTotal}/> }
   />
```

Child component:

```
function Dashboard(props) {
  const [selectedSort, setSelectedSort] = useState("1")
  const [devices, setDevices] = useState(props.data)

  useEffect(() => {
    props.refresh(); 
    setDevices(props.data)
  },[devices])

useEffect(() => sortDeviceData(), [selectedSort])



   const sortDeviceData = () => {

    console.log(devices)
    switch(selectedSort) {
      case "device":
        console.log(devices)
        props.data.sort(function(a,b) {
          return (a.device_id.toUpperCase() < b.device_id.toUpperCase()) ? -1 : (a.device_id.toUpperCase() > b.device_id.toUpperCase()) ? 1 : 0
        })
        setDevices(props.data)
        break;
      case "customer":
        props.data.sort(function(a,b) {
          return (a.customer.toUpperCase() < b.customer.toUpperCase()) ? -1 : (a.customer.toUpperCase() > b.customer.toUpperCase()) ? 1 : 0
        })
        setDevices(props.data)
        break;
      case "server":
        props.data.sort(function(a,b) {
          return (a.server.toUpperCase() < b.server.toUpperCase()) ? -1 : (a.server.toUpperCase() > b.server.toUpperCase()) ? 1 : 0
        })
        setDevices(props.data)
        break;
      case "creation":
        props.data.sort(function(a,b) {
          return (a.createdAt.toUpperCase() < b.createdAt.toUpperCase()) ? -1 : (a.createdAt.toUpperCase() > b.createdAt.toUpperCase()) ? 1 : 0
        })
        setDevices(props.data)
        break;
      case "update":
        props.data.sort(function(a,b) {
          return (a.updatedAt.toUpperCase() < b.updatedAt.toUpperCase()) ? -1 : (a.updatedAt.toUpperCase() > b.updatedAt.toUpperCase()) ? 1 : 0
        })
        setDevices(props.data)
        break;    
      default: 
        return setDevices(props.data)
    }
  }

<div>
          <FormControl className={classes.selectContainer}>

            <Select 
              value={selectedSort} 
              style={{position: 'absolute', right: 0, bottom: 10, width: 150}}
              onChange={e => setSelectedSort(e.target.value)}
              >
              <MenuItem value="1">Sort</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="device">Device</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="customer">User</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="server">Server</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="creation">Creation date</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="update">Update date</MenuItem>
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
        <div>
          <DeviceList
            classes={classes}
            deviceData={devices ? devices: props.data}
            filtered={props.filtered}
          />
        </div>
```

Comment: I think its better to use  switch... case than multiple if condition

Comment: try changing attribute value in select to defaultValue and check

Comment: @AkhilAravind, about switch, actually true, I forgot I can use it, rewrote it already to switch, about defaultValue, it doesn't work

Comment: do you have a stackblitz example for the same, and what package are you using for `select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your refresh changes props asynchronous, so in useEffect props.data ist still null or whatever initial value you give it.
Then when props.data is set (from the resolved promise in refresh) the component is rerendered. But since devices is unchanged useEffect does not execute again and devices will never be set to the new values from props.data.

I advice you to decide if the parent controls fetching the data, then you can just pass devices into this component, or this component does the fetch, then you could just take the code from refresh an replace setData with a state setter from this component inside a useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(....
    .then(json => setDevices(json.devices)
}, [])
```

This would run once, on first render and the arrival of data triggers rerender with devices.

To avoid devices.sort is not a function add a guard: if (devices) ...

Comment: If I'm not wrong, I do all this what you said, I fetch it and launch it on componentDidMount moment with useEffect, then data should be fetched and passed via props to child component, and since that moment child component should change data by sort function and based on change it should initialize refresh() function. I edited my question to clarify everything what happens in my code

Comment: it works! finally! I kinda mixed up all your ideas, added a bit from myself and it works, now I gotta clean up a code as I made sort of mess but most important that goal is achieved and now just polishing the code:) Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

just make sortDeviceData a function of selectedSort and pass selectedSort in:

```
const sortDeviceData = selectedSort => {...}
```

Since selectedSort is not used in your useEffect, it is not being executed.

Comment: but in useEffect I use selectedSort as a parameter which needs to be observed, so useEffect should see it and updates if selectedSort is changed. Passing selectedSort as a parameter makes that it is not working at all unfortunatelly

Answer (score 0):

Ok, maybe I am not quite sure what is happening. I assume you get the devices originally from props.data?

Then you could omit the first useEffect by using props.data in useState for devices:

```
const [devices, setDevices] = useState(props.data)
```

Then when you change the sort-order, you should not update props.data inplace - props ought to be read-only!

Personally I would write a function to return the comparator given the selectedSort:

```
const comparator = selector => {
  switch (selector) {
    case „1“: return (a,b)=>...
    ...
  }
}
```

and then do

```
useEffect(() => setDevices(devices.sort(comparator(selectedSort)))
  , [selectedSort])
```

Comment: sorry for editing your post but wanted to add props.refresh and clicked on your post instead of mine... anyway maybe the issue is somewhere else> I mean when I try to do your way it says that device.sort is not a function, the thing is that ```const [devices, setDevices] = useState(props.data)``` doesn't update the devices, It is all time empty, same my previous useEffects also seem to not have any impact on state of device. It changes only after I click on some values in Select two times

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching data in your child which sets state in the parent. This you pass through to your child as data. But then you call refresh in useEffect, which is async, so your setting the old props.data once again.

Delete the useEffect in your child where you refresh, and use props.data as your initial prop to useState for devices.

The refresh property of dashboard can be removed.

Your parent is in control of data-fetching, so rely on the parent to do.